# Input files with different columns to be loaded in single Nifi flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some input files with different column names. Can I create a common Nifi flow which processes all the types of files? Each files will be having different types of columns and different types of output table to be loaded. For example, File 1 will be having column A, Column B to be loaded to Table AB, File 2 will be having column C, Column D, Column E to be loaded to Table CDE. Can I achieve this in a single flow or should I create different flows for different types of files? I am new to Nifi, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a single flow, perhaps with RouteOnContent to look for the header so you know which type of file it is. Each outgoing connection would correspond to a different type of file / output table, so you could have an UpdateAttribute on the other end of each outgoing connection, to set attributes for things like the table name, possibly the record schema (if using record-based processors, which I recommend), etc. Then you can use a funnel to merge the sub-flows, or just connect all the outgoing connections to whatever the next downstream processor is (PutDatabaseTable for example).

If you don't want to split the flow at all, you'd probably need to do the same work of identifying the file type and setting the attributes, but from a single script (using ExecuteScript for example). In any case, the downstream processors should be able to make use of the attributes using [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) such that the same processor can handle the different file types appropriately.